# How do you find out what headers you need to install in a C project on linux?

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile

I haven't compiled a C project in a while, but I do remember running `./configure` or `make configure --prefix=/home/userName/somedir` and then running `make install`

But when I would actually compile it alot of the time it would throw errors and I would just google or post in a mailing group to find out which headers I needed to install to compile it.

Is there a way to use the `MakeFile` or `automake` to find out what headers I am missing?

Comment: It's not "headers" you need, but the packages that those headers represent.  A package in C (or C++) consists of headers and also libraries that need to be linked containing the code (headers are just declarations, except for some C++ packages that implement everything in header files).  Usually you look at the README file for the package to find out what other packages it depends on.  Alternatively, sometimes if you run `./configure --help` it will show you options on how to specify paths to needed packages and you can infer them from that.

Comment: Not really. C and its ecosystem are horrible at dependency management, compared to more modern languages. You read the documentation and hope that the author bothered to include the requirements for your particular OS/distro. Then you prod it until it runs. For headers, you can look at the source files themselves, but that's not the whole story; you need the whole library and sometimes a particular version of it.